# boto3 - 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters

Tags: python, utf-8, boto3

I am using boto3 to upload a file to S3:

```
s3client.upload_file(
     '/path/to/file',
     'destination-bucket',
     'destination-object-name')
```

which works when I run it under my local development environment (Ubuntu 18.04, python 3.8), however when deployed to dev server (using the same Docker container!) I get

```
ERROR - 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 83-84: surrogates not allowed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myscript.py", line 1, in sync_with_s3
    s3client.upload_file(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 129, in upload_file
```

So I check which byte is at position 83-84 and find:

```
with open('/path/to/file', 'rb') as f:
     print(f.read()[83:84])
# b'\x00'
```

When I look this byte up in UTF-8 table, I see that `b'\x00'` is the NULL character. I don't see why this would result in the error above.

How can I proceed to debug this?

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: `surrogates not allowed` indicates that there is a sequence of bytes that's causing the problem - not just a single byte.  Is it possible that the file originated from a system that uses UTF-16 as it's encoding?

Comment: Or perhaps the file is *not* UTF8 at all, but some other encoding? Or perhaps it's not a text file at all?

Comment: Yes it's a msg file (from microsoft outlook). it could very well be that it was not encoded in utf-8. what can i do in that case if I dont know the original encoding?